# Validation of textarea fields always fails in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a custom validator for forms, where validation rules are extracted from a database table. The validator works fine, untill I use it on a textarea. The rule is simple, 'required', but validation always fails even when there is data sent.

```
$rules = $this->getFormRules($slug);
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to($request->uri)
        ->withErrors($validator);
} else { ... }

private function getFormRules($slug = null) {
    $elements = Element::all();
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        if(isset($element->mandatory) == 1) {
            $rules_array[$element->field_name] = 'required';
        }
    }
    return $rules_array;
}
```

The rules array is like:

```
Array (
    [Name] => required
    [E-mail] => required
    [Company] => required
    [Phone] => required
    [Message] => required 
)
```

`Message` is the textarea and there it keeps on failing

```
<form method="POST" action="/form-send" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden"name="_token"value="8ZtkSm7QkloWxAH5x3KkAzW2BS1UEpLv4SkuJ1Nu">
    <input type="hidden" name="uri" value="/contact">
    <div>
        <label>Name<span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>E-mail<span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="E-mail" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Company</label>
        <input type="text" name="Company" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="Phone" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Message<span>*</span></label>
        <textarea name="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="Send">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is the `name` on the `Message` textarea set correctly? If you do a `dd(Input::get('Message'))` do you see the text?

Comment: Yes I do. Even when I print the output it shows the value

Comment: Can you update the question with the form also?

Comment: Done Jilson. See question

Comment: Please could you post your model code

Comment: Do you have another input with the name of Message?

Comment: No I do not have another input with the same name

Comment: BKF, My model is empty